# Embedding <script>, <div> obtained from python in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, cgi

I have a python script that creates `UTF-8` encoded `<script>` and `<div>` tags. How can I embed them in my `index.html`? Example:

`<script>` and `<div>` elements are created in `script.py`:

```
s = "<script type = "text/javascript">function(){console.log("Hello")}</script>"
su = unicode(s, "utf-8")

d = "<div><p>World</p></div>"
du = unicode(d, "utf-8")
```

`index.html` functions as follows:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">function(){console.log("Hello")}</script>
</head>

<body>
<div><p>World</p></div>
</body>
```

`script.py` is NOT on the same server as `index.html`. How can I embed `su` and `du` in `index.html`? The desired `index.html` would look something like:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<head>
<!--Insert JavaScript that fetches su from script.py-->
</head>

<body>
<!--Insert JavaScript that fetches du from script.py-->
</body>
```

Additional info: `script.py` is accessed through Apache and executed as a cgi-script.

Answer (score 0):

use django web framework to deal with python   or use ajax request to the server that contain your py script

Comment: Using Ajax seems the easiest, so do I return the values from the script by calling print and somehow receive them in Ajax? Could you be a bit more specific